# Парсер mail.ru

Tags: php, парсер

Доброго вам друзья. Я пишу парсер емэйлов mail.ru моя цель вот эта ссылка

```
http://my.mail.ru/my/search_people?st=city&Password=&city_id=1092&Domain=&Login=
```

С помощью вот такого кода я обращаюсь к странице

```
//Javascript я свиснул с сайта сграбь.ру (подсказали на этом сайте)
<a href="javascript:(function(){window.name=document.location+'|||'+document.body.innerHTML;
document.location='http://geepars.ru/';})()">Украсть</a>

<?//сюда приходит полный адрес то есть  http://my.mail.ru/my/search_people?st=city&Password=&city_id=1092&Domain=&Login=
$file = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$file2 = file_get_contents($file);
//В текстовый документ я закидываю исходный код! только адресов там НЕТ))
file_put_contents("ishodnik.txt",$file2,FILE_APPEND);
```

Если я в ручную вытаскиваю исходный код (правой кнопкой мыши) то всё работает! У меня есть продолжение, скрипт ищет адреса и преобразовывает их в правильные мэйлы. Мне осталось обратиться к странице и сделать так чтобы скрипт проходил до конца страницы и переключался на другую

Comment: Сначала скажите как обращаетесь к исходному коду страницы вообще?

Comment: Если есть интересная статья об этом буду рад прочитать

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ: правой клавишей мыши в браузере, там "View source". Ну или wget "http://site.com????q=q&a=a&b=b"

Comment: Я исправил вопрос

Comment: И что не как не обойти?

Comment: Обойти что? Вы сравнили контент, нашли в чём именно он отличается?

Comment: нет там ссылок которые мне нужны! http://my.mail.ru/mail/betaika/ вот такие. проверьте они есть когда правой кнопкой мыши смотришь исходный код а  так НЕТ!$file = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$file2 = file_get_contents($file);

Comment: Что там нет ссылок вы уже сказали. А что есть-то? Могу только предположить, что отдаётся страница с урезанным функционалом, из-за отсутствия авторизации (судя по вашему коду). Но что на самом деле отдаётся можете сказать только вы, так далеко моя телепатия не работает. Например, сохраните страницу на диск и откройте в браузере, если по коду глазами пройтись сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl`-ом по ходу надо забирать страницу или

```
fopen(http://my.mail.ru/my/search_people?st=city&Password=&city_id=1092&Domain=&Login=)
$file = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; //в этой переменной будет хранится ссылка на предыдущую страницу
```

Если проблема в авторизации, то `curl` с отправкой данных на сервер